# Which one is better to use keep silen t/ce

Tags: grammar

How it'll be better to say:
Keep silent or keep silence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatical: keep functions as both a copulative and transitive verb, so can be used both with adjectives (keep silent, keep still) and nouns (keep silence, keep possession).

However, "keep silent" is far more idiomatic for telling people to be quiet, though "keep silence" might be used in a more formal context to emphasise the collective nature of the silence ("please keep silence in hall").

Interestingly, historically "keep silence" was the more common form, but is now much rarer: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keep+silent%2Ckeep+silence&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckeep%20silent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckeep%20silence%3B%2Cc0).